# issue with spring bean configuration - Error processing XML Spring 4.0.2

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring 4.0.2  with eclipse kepler and I am facing following error while configuring component scan in my bean configuration.

[image]

please find my spring configuration file as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/static/**" />
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ashish.spring.web.controller">
    </context:component-scan>


    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename"
        value="com.ashish.spring.web.message.messages">
    </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Not nearly enough information to say exactly where the problem is, but you're trying to pass a `String[]` to something expecting a `String`.

Comment: Your config is correct, see the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-scanning-autodetection)

Comment: problem may be in xsd try another..